# Write to existing columns based on values in another column in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, geocoding

I have CSV file that contains entries of businesses with a column of the cities they are based in as well as 2 columns of inaccurate latitudinal coordinates and longitudinal coordinates that need replacing.

```
'Company',   'Location',   'Lat',      'Lon'
'Xconic',    'Austin',      11.263406, -85.8639766
'InfoTech',  'London',      12.078980, -86.2094965
'WaterForm', 'Toronto',     12.865416, -85.2072295
```

I need to make a script that will read through the 'Location' column, take each city name string and run it through the [google geocoder function](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geocoder) to find lat and long coordinates for it. The script then has to overwrite the corresponding 'Lat' and 'Lon' entries for that row with the ones produced by the geocoder function.

I originally tried to turn the CSV into a dataframe to iterate directly over the location category using the following code:

```
#Create dataframe from CSV file
import pandas as pd
file= "filein.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file)

x = 0

#Iterate over location names
import geocoder
import csv
for item in data.Location:
    #produce lat & long coordinates
    g = geocoder.google(item)

    Latx = str(data.Lat[x]) 
    Latx = g.lat

    Lngx = str(data.Lon[x])
    Lngx = g.lng
```

while this code could produce lat/long coordinates for each entry, I have been completely at odds with trying to write these coordinates (Latx & Lngx) into the 'Lat' and 'Lon' columns. Not sure if its because I need to rewrite the columns into a completely new CSV or what.

I am pretty new python so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Super! you've defined the problem that you're trying to solve. Now, show us what you've tried, and we'll show you how to improve it

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thanks! I added what I have got thus far.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really replace values in an existing file. Instead, what you can do is:

**1.** Read an existing file

**2.** Alter file in memory(perform operations-in your case modifies values)

**3.** Write out new file (overwriting existing file)

Also you can read the file line-by-line and after manipulation write it to the new file. When done, close both files, delete the original and rename the new file.

Hope this helps & you got the point.

Cheers!!